# How to improve my question - Why is there so much reluctant sex in hentai?

Tags: discussion

How do I improve my question:

[Why is there so much reluctant sex in hentai?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22448/why-is-there-so-much-rape-in-hentai)

[s]'Cause I got 3 Downvotes without comments, so... what is wrong now?

Should I delete and move the question to Chat or here on Meta?[/s]

All good now!

Comment: Related: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21/is-discussing-hentai-allowed

On chat, there should be somebody willing to have a discussion about it. It all depends on who's online at the time.

Comment: also possibly related [Terms Of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), see the minimum subscriber age... It's 13.

Comment: I think your current version of the question is reasonable. At this point it just goes back to our eternal war over whether we want to field hentai-related questions or not (most of the community, including me, seems to think yes, as long as they're tasteful, which I think the current version of your question is). If you don't mind, there are some edits for clarity that I can make; feel free to roll back if they distort the question you want to ask.

Comment: There is nothing sexually explicit about the question at all. The language in the question is also reasonable and not vulgar, so I don't think it violate the TOS. As for the minimum subscriber's age, it seems that many users deem even mention of anything sexual inappropriate for 13 year old - well, that's still up for debate, though it's more of community decision, rather than TOS.

Comment: Keep in mind that downvotes are entirely opinion-based and we can't enforce them. If you got 3 downvotes, 3 people didn't like the question, but it doesn't mean it was bad! (Still, kudos for asking how to improve it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, it's great that you want to improve your question. Don't let the downvotes discourage you. I for one am always happy for new brains here.

It's a little bit late now for me to give advice, as much seems to have transpired - but I'll give you a small recap.

- The question was declined first because it was more or less asking for **an opinion on the existing answers you had**. This at least, was why I would have cast the close vote.
- Explicitly hentai (as in, *clearly* hentai) is **a point of division** between some users here - this probably contributed to getting some downvotes too - along with the opinion-based reason.
- Once your question was closed, it took a few hours to re-open. Users probably **discussed** between themselves about what to do with the question - taking some more time that usual because of the divide - and some other users probably didn't feel they knew the rules well enough to make the call.

Anyway, it's reopened now **:)**